# How to return value from Runnable Interface using FutureTask

Tags: java, multithreading

I did lot of google but I could not find how to return value from Runnable interface using FutureTask.

I need to return outcome of run method using FutureTask, I know that same can be archived using Callable Interface but how it can be done using Runnable Interface.

FutureTask constructor accepts second parameter for return value.

```
    public FutureTask(Runnable runnable,V result)
```

How to assign outcome of run() method to V result.

```
    FutureTask<String> futureTask=new FutureTask<String>(new Runnable() {           
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String outcome="Task Completed Successfully";
        }
    },null);
```

Comment: **You can't** set that parameter from within `run`. But this is exactly what `Callable` is for. Why not use `Callable`?

Comment: By the way, interfaces don't *do* anything.

Comment: I can use Callable interface but what the use     public FutureTask(Runnable runnable,V result)

Comment: The use of that is when you have a Runnable, and you know the result in advance. Such as if the result is always "Task Completed Successfully" in AJNeufeld's answer. Or if it's always null.

Comment: Sorry but if I know result in advance then why do I need to pass it.

Comment: Probably because you can't have a `FutureTask` with no result.

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    }
});
Future fs = exec.submit(new Callable() {
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return null;//yourObject
    }
});
fs.get();//your object
```

Answer (score 0):

The `null` value in your call is the return value.  To have it return  `"Task Completed Successfully"`, you'd need:

```
FutureTask<String> futureTask=new FutureTask<String>(new Runnable() {           
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}, "Task Completed Successfully");
```

This is clearly not very useful if you want the `Runnable` to compute a result, however.

Use a `Callable`, instead.